# Would a Pokémon-based app be rejected from the App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore

I’m curious about if an app that would use the name of Pokémon, and using images and sprites from this universe would be rejected or not. My first guess would be yes, even more now that Niantic and The Pokémon Company have released many official Pokémon games. But after a quick look on the App Store, I discovered a few of them:

https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/oak-dex-team-builder-guides/id1097232463?l=en
https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/pok%C3%A9quiz-unofficial-quiz-for-pok%C3%A9mon/id1164928511?l=en
https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/poke-genie/id1143920524?l=en

It looks like most of these apps don’t show actual sprites on their screenshots, still they use the official name Pokémon. What to think about this?

Comment: Only Apple can tell you if this is allowed or not.  If you've seen other apps that are similar to what you want to build, then it looks like Apple allows it.  Otherwise, they probably don't because you're not the trademark owner and you don't have permission.

Comment: I’d ask your lawyer and not the internet for an opinion here. If this is about understanding the T&C of app review we would need more of your research to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

While only the Apple's App Store Review team could answer that, but most likely it may (unless you in compliance with the condition linked below). It's likely to get rejected on the ground of copyright violations.

From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) document:

*[Section 5.2 Intellectual Property](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property)*

> **5.2.1** Generally: Don’t use protected third-party material such as trademarks, copyrighted works, or patented ideas in your app without permission, and don’t include misleading, false, or copycat representations, names, or metadata in your app bundle or developer name. Apps should be submitted by the person or legal entity that owns or has licensed the intellectual property and other relevant rights and is responsible for offering any services provided by the app.